# How can I allow users to add documents to a library but not be able to open other documents listed?

Tags: document-library

I am hoping to create a virtual dumping ground for users to upload their confidential documents, but not be able to open/read/edit other documents. Is a document library the best option? I know if I use a List, I can restrict viewing to only what the user creates, but this is not an option for Libraries.

Eventually, I want the supervisor of a team to be able to edit each document in their team's document library (to leave their feedback). Not sure if a workflow should be applied or not.

Got a big task ahead of me and am a novice SharePoint user! Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could accomplish this in a Document Library using permission levels...

For example, you can create a new Permission Level and only give it 'Add Items' and 'View Items' permissions for lists. This means that a user can add items to lists and view items in a list but not open the items. So he can basically see the items in the list but not their content (someone pls correct me if I am wrong here). Then you could assign this permission level to all users that can 'dump' their documents and give the supervisor higher permissions so he can edit the documents (probably contribute permissions is ok).

I'm not sure if this is the preferred approach but its just an idea and I have not tested this out, but I think permissions are the way to go. In my current site, I have Restricted Read permissions on certain department libraries for all users except those that belong to that department, that way everyone can see/open the files but only those from the department can upload and edit documents.

Here are some of the documents I've been reading for permissions:
http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/01/sharepoint-security-and-permission-system-overview/ (this article helps A LOT with understanding how permisions work)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/basics-what-are-permissions-HA101810704.aspx

Anyway, I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying...but I believe the View Items permissions still allows users to view documents within the browser :(

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure then. I just tried the Permission Level and like you said it does allow viewing of the documents. I would hope that there is a way to create that type of permission, maybe someone else can come in with an idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter to the view.  Filter it down to the user who created the file.  If the users have contributor rights on the library however, you might have to do the permissions thing that Tudor expressed in the other answer, else they will be able to create new views.

[image]

Comment: I think securing with a view is not real security as user can find a way to create their own security.

Comment: Does anybody have a SP 2013 Workflow example of changing/breaking inherited permissions on a Doc Library FILE?