# Securing files in a library by a people column?

Tags: document-library, security, column, people-picker

SharePoint Online 2013.

Library with a people column added.

For the site owner, they can add files at will, but must select a person for that column for every file.

But for library members, we don't want them to be able to delete, save or even view files that are not associated with their user in the people column. They can add new files, delete files and edit files, but the files must have their user in that people column.

Possible with stock SP 2013? How?

Also, how will it work if either user type drags a bunch of files over at once and their are other required columns?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question on SE, titled [How can I allow users to add documents to a library but not be able to open other documents listed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/45632/16290).

Cite Answer 1:

> You can create a new Permission Level and only give it 'Add Items' and 'View Items' permissions for lists. This means that a user can add items to lists and view items in a list but not open the items. So he can basically see the items in the list but not their content (someone pls correct me if I am wrong here). Then you could assign this permission level to all users that can 'dump' their documents and give the supervisor higher permissions so he can edit the documents (probably contribute permissions is ok).

Cite Answer 2:

> You can add a filter to the view. Filter it down to the user who created the file. If the users have contributor rights on the library however, you might have to do the permissions thing that Tudor expressed in the other answer, else they will be able to create new views.

Comment: Thanks but the view [me] filter is not real security and add only does not address the need to edit and delete "their" own records.

Comment: I attempted the Add and View with a Doc Library in SPO 2013 and it did not work.. i dont' think that works in 2007 or 2010 either.  Has anybody broken/changed inherited permissions using a 2013 Workflow on a Doc Lib on SPO 2013?